# Irreducible closed subsets of projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I want to prove the following lemma:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety. Let $W \subset X$ be a closed irreducible set. Then $W$ is also a projective variety.

My idea is as follows, we can write
$$ X = \mathcal{V}(f_1,...,f_m)$$
as the set of zeroes of homogeneous polynomials $f_1,...,f_m$. Since $W$ is Zariski closed and $W \subset X$ we can write
$$ W = \mathcal{V}(f_1,...,f_m, g_1,...,g_l)$$ 
where $g_1,...,g_l$ are homogeneous polynomial. I need to show it is a projective variety using the fact that it is irreducible.

However, from the book 
[Hulek, *Elementary Algebraic Geometry*] Definition 2.6 $W$ is a projective variety (subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$ which is a set of zeroes of set of homogeneous polynomial equations). Where does the role of irreducibility take place? I didn't use it, at least explicitly. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Some people include irreducibility in their definition of "variety".

Comment: @Zhen Lin Thanks. The motivation for proving this Lemma is to show that $Y = \mathbb{P}^2-\{(1:0:0)\}$ is not isomorphic to any projecive variety by finding a closed irreducible subset of $Y$ which is not a projective variety. I thought proving this lemma will give me intuition how to find this subset.

Comment: Well, it is certainly the case that every closed irreducible subset of a projective variety is a projective variety. But if your definition of "projective variety" does not include irreducibility then even every closed subset of a projective variety is a projective variety. Therefore if $Y$ has a irreducible closed subset that is not a projective variety, then $Y$ cannot be projective.

Comment: I thought on the closed set $Y \cap \mathcal{V}(x_1)$ as a closed subset of $Y$ which is not a projective variety.